# Intuition on KL-divergence and feature selection

Tags: decision-tree, information-theory

I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding KL-divergence and how I can use it for feature selection. So let's say I have a set of observations (e.g. zeroes and ones) and a 2 features generated for each observation. My question now is: why feature is the 'best'?

I know I can use KL-divergence (given by $$D_{KL} = \sum_i p(i) \log \frac{p(i)}{q(i)}$$), however what is P and what is Q? My intuition says that P is e.g. feature 1 and Q is the true distributions (so the set of zeroes and ones), but it is also my understand that a good feature maximizes the KL-divergence. But if Q is the actual distribution of classes then you want to minimize it right? So the feature distribution does not err badly on the actual distribution?

Answer (score 0):

KL divergence has the same formula as mutual information. Mutual information explains correlation between variables.

Answer (score 0):

KL divergence is used for feature selection as the amount of entropy in marginal probability of the target reduced by the entropy of the target given the feature:

```
I(t ; f) = H(t)-H(t|f)
```

To put it another way, it calculates the KL divergence of the product of marginals of the target and the feature and their joint probability.

```
I(t ; f) = KL(p(t,f)||p(t)*p(f))
```

Find more [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/information-gain-and-mutual-information/).